# Can't resolve "Support" in namespace "Android.Support.V7.App"

Tags: xamarin

I use Visual Studio 2019 and I have downloaded all packages for `Xamarin.Android` project, but when I write:

`using Android.Widget;`

and then in `OnCreate` method I write:

`Button b = new Button(this);`

I have no problem. But when I try to use the full namespace like this:

`Android.Widget.Button b = new Android.Widget.Button(this);`

I have a problem with intellisense. It doesn't offer me the `Widget` namespace but `Net` namespace instead. I have installed all required packages.

So what can I do to have my `Widget` namespace in Button's full namespace ?

Comment: I am not a Visual Studio user. I can't answer for sure. What I think is since you have imported Android.Widget, IntelliSense (code completion aiding tool) thinks you are not going to use the full path. Hope it helps! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `Android` in your own namespace, which then will clash. I.e. your namespace is `MyApp.Android`.

You can fully qualify the namespace and prefix it with `global::` to get around this:

```
var button = new global::Android.Widget.Button(this);
```